# How to handle long-running unstable server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, architecture

We have an old monolith system that is unstable, 95% of the requests are processed within 500ms but the other 5% takes > 10sec and the connection times out. I would like to make our service more resilient. The communication is done through REST and the [architecture is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je0DP.jpg).

Our current approach is to use an async http client with an exponential backoff retry mechanism. But this will cause performance issues as the traffic  increases

My idea is to have a synchronous http call in S with a timeout of 500ms and a fallback method that adds a task to the queue for retrying the http request in the future, while returning a 202 to C along with a link to check the status of the task something like `/queue/task-123`. I know that I need to make S exposed service to C idempotent so I will have to check the queue every time I receive a new request from C to be sure that I do not have duplicate tasks.

Questions:

1. Is there a better approach to solve my problem?
2. Is a task in a queue the best way to handle a retry in a REST endpoint?

Our stack: Java using Spring boot and for a queue I think RabbitMQ

Comment: I know that the real solution is to fix the underlying issue but my goal is to make the service as resilience as possible. It's not so much on how to solve the problem but how to protect ourselves from these types of incidences in the future.

Comment: When you say 95% are OK and 5% are not, does the server go through a period where all requests time out and then the server recovers and all requests are OK again, or do you get the occasional single request that times out even though other requests around the same time are fine?

Comment: @ChrisC Other requests are fine but this request takes a long of time. But as I said this is not the point of the question. What I want to achieve is to increase the resilience of my service and not solve the underlying issue.

Comment: OK, but it can be useful info to know in terms of the retry handing. I think your suggested approach is ok, but you could also consider a call back rather than the client having to poll an endpoint. The task on a queue is a good approach because it stops the client from retrying endlessly and instead you're just promising to get to them when you get to it. You will need duplicate checking on the tasks, but I don't know RabbitMQ enough to know whether you can interrogate the messages on the queue to compare payloads... Maybe a DB of recent msg hashes?

Answer (score 0):

Have the requests to S create Futures for the AsyncHttpResponse, and send them to an Executor with a thread pool large enough to accommodate your load, but not so high that it will swamp your Monolith.  That way when things start failing, it will not snowball on you, and the other requests can queue.  You could still have a retry model in this model, but have it be controlled outside the future so that it will allow successful requests to come in before the retries.